# Does the imlementation of std::string, I use, implement ref-counting or not?

Tags: c++, string, ios, stl

I develop for iOS and use XCode 3.2.5, GCC 4.2.

UPD

This code works:

```
string s = "aaaa";
string s1 = s;

assert(s.data() == s1.data());
```

Does it mean ref-counting is used? Or '==' is overloaded for const char* somehow to compare contents, not addresses?

UPD

Okay, it does.

Comment: I do not know of any version of `std::string` that does any reference-counting. What gives you that idea?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y libstdc++'s (aka gcc's) implementation of std::string does reference counting to do copy-on-write.

Comment: @Migi: Thanks, I learned something today!

Comment: It depends in which gcc version you use. Later versions have abandoned the refcounting.

Comment: Bo: gcc 4.8.1 uses refcounting for std::basic_string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways of finding out, the first of which is plainly looking at the code. `std::string` is a typedef to an instantiation of the `basic_string` template, and being a template, all the code is available to you in the headers. Note that reading standard library headers can be both enlightening and hard. And yet, you don't even need to *understand* the code, you might get some good hints from a cursory look (as by the fact that `basic_string` contains a member `_M_p` with a `_M_refcount` sub member)

If you don't want to read the code, you can approach the problem from a practical point of view and *measure* the effects that a *copy-on-write* implementation would have. You can, for example create a long string [*], then copy it to a different string and compare the addresses of the `data()` that stores the actual contents.

[*] The reason for the *long* string is to avoid getting confused with some other implementations, as small object implementation that could be used by the compiler and by which a string could contain a small buffer to avoid dynamic memory allocations for very small uses.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to find out would be to copy-construct or assign a string, and compare the results of their `data()` method - if their data area is at the same location in memory, they must be using some form of reference counting.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious answer is: it's unspecified.  As far as I know, it's
not only unspecified in the standard, but in every
implementation.  But for what it's worth, g++ uses a reference
counted implementation, at least through the latest version I've
looked at (4.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

ref counting is really useful, copy on write...etc.   a lot of code relies on it to be efficient.   it's probably a bad idea to abandon it.   better to have a function that explicitly obtains a copy of a string the way MS does it (lock buffer, etc.) if you're going to tinker with internals in an unsafe manner.